# Page not found at /archive/

Tags: django

**EDIT: Figured it out, please see bottom.**

I'm writing a simple blog app in Django and deploying it locally using [this](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/get-started-django) guide. I've completed the guide and everything was nominal so I decided to extend the functionality to view an archive of blog posts. This is how the index functions at the moment, but I wanted to move it to /archive/. I went to the tutorial again to get refresh my memory and it said I had to do three things:

1. Write the root URLconf in urls.py
2. Write the view function in views.py
3. Write the templates for the views

I edited the URLconf to look like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #other patterns
    url(r'^archive/', 'RehabLog.views.archive'),
)
```

I edited my views.py to add this function:

```
def archive(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published=True)
    return render(request, 'RehabLog/archive.html', {'posts':posts})
```

I've saved it all and restarted foreman. When I load the page I get a 404 error which tells me **No Post matches the given query**. What am I missing out on?

**Answer**

I remembered reading the the order of your URLConfs was very important.

Previously I had:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', 'RehabLog.views.index'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 'RehabLog.views.post'),
    url(r'^archive/', 'RehabLog.views.archive'),
)
```

Whereas now I have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^archive/', 'RehabLog.views.archive'),
    url(r'^$', 'RehabLog.views.index'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 'RehabLog.views.post'),
)
```

Which now works. Could anyone explain why?

Comment: Please provide the full error stacktrace

Comment: Could you please provide the complete error log.

Comment: @matino I figured it out. Please see above.

Comment: you should post your answer as an answer. or delete the question.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I can't do that under 10 reputation. It told me to edit the question or post it under a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/archive/` URL was first-matched by `url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 'RehabLog.views.post')` so your actual rule `url(r'^archive/', 'RehabLog.views.archive')` was never reached. When you changed the order the first rule matched was the right one.